# String to DateTime, TryParse was not enough

Tags: c#, datetime, string-parsing

Here's a method that works:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Checks date validity.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="candidate">String to check</param>
        /// <returns>Whether valid and result as a date</returns>
        private static Tuple<bool, DateTime?> ParseDate(string candidate)
        {
            DateTime result;
            if(DateTime.TryParseExact(candidate, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result) ||
                DateTime.TryParseExact(candidate, "dd.M.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result) ||
                DateTime.TryParseExact(candidate, "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result) ||
                DateTime.TryParseExact(candidate, "d.M.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result) ||
                DateTime.TryParseExact(candidate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result) ||
                DateTime.TryParseExact(candidate, "dd/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result) ||
                DateTime.TryParseExact(candidate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result) ||
                DateTime.TryParseExact(candidate, "d/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result) ||
                DateTime.TryParseExact(candidate, "dd.MM.yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result) ||
                DateTime.TryParseExact(candidate, "dd.M.yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result) ||
                DateTime.TryParseExact(candidate, "dd.MM.yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result) ||
                DateTime.TryParseExact(candidate, "d.M.yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result) ||
                DateTime.TryParseExact(candidate, "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result) ||
                DateTime.TryParseExact(candidate, "dd/M/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result) ||
                DateTime.TryParseExact(candidate, "dd/MM/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result) ||
                DateTime.TryParseExact(candidate, "d/M/yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result)
            )
            {
                return new Tuple<bool, DateTime?>(true, result);
            }

            return new Tuple<bool, DateTime?>(false, null);
        }
```

Seems pretty useless to me to add tons of or-branches there. What would be a smarter way to do this? I thought DateTime.TryParse would do it, but it managed to somehow fail with 15.6.2020 (this past Monday) and return that it is not a valid date.

And yeah, I have a million or-branches missing from there, I know. That's also a big problem here that I'd like help with.

Comment: Have you just tried parsing using the appropriate culture?  It seems like `"dd.M.yyyy"` should have done the trick - did you try this in a debugger?  If you really want to use all those format strings, put them in a collection and use a foreach (you'll need to re-arrange your logic, but it shouldn't be that hard). This code works for me (`DateTime.TryParseExact(candidate, "dd.M.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out var result);`) with an input of `var candidate = "15.6.2020";`.  You'd enjoy the use - people here insist on putting the month number first.

Comment: Yeah i didn't notice that. good point. ill delete my comment

Comment: Consider splitting the string into its three components and calling https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_ . _You may need special code to handle 2 digit years._

Comment: `I thought DateTime.TryParse would do it, but it managed to somehow fail with 15.6.2020 (this past Monday) and return that it is not a valid date.` Please show us that code.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of date formats and some are custom, which is why you need to specify what valid format you will accept. It will be helpful if you can validate the format or limit the accepted format in the UI (if the date comes from some kind of a manual input). In DateTime.TryParseExact, there is an overload that accepts an array of string formats see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netcore-3.1#System_DateTime_TryParseExact_System_String_System_String___System_IFormatProvider_System_Globalization_DateTimeStyles_System_DateTime__)

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to match the string format against. Something like

```cs
public bool IsStringDate(string candidate){

    var dateRegex = new Regex("^([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\/([2][01]|[1][6-9])\d{2}(\s([0-1]\d|[2][0-3])(\:[0-5]\d){1,2})?$");

    return dateRegex.Match(candidate).Success;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keeping your same logic, I wrote this:

```
public static bool TryParseDateTimeManyFormats(string toParse, out DateTime result)
{
    result = default;
    foreach (var format in DateFormats)
    {
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(toParse, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,
            out result))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

accompanied by your list of date formats.  Then I kept eliminating them until I got a minimal set:

```
private static readonly string[] DateFormats =
{
    //"dd.MM.yyyy",
    //"dd.M.yyyy",
    //"dd.MM.yyyy",
    "d.M.yyyy",
    //"dd/MM/yyyy",
    //"dd/M/yyyy",
    //"dd/MM/yyyy",
    "d/M/yyyy",
    //"dd.MM.yy",
    //"dd.M.yy",
    //"dd.MM.yy",
    "d.M.yy",
    //"dd/MM/yy",
    //"dd/M/yy",
    //"dd/MM/yy",
    "d/M/yy",
};
```

Then I wrote a little test harness that looks like:

```
public static void TestDateParsing()
{
    string[] dates =
    {
        "31.1.1919",
        "22/01/1957",
        "1/2/2020",
        "03/04/1812",
        "1/2/03",
        "04/05/06",
        "30/2/2010",
        "15.6.2020",
    };

    foreach (var date in dates)
    {
        if (TryParseDateTimeManyFormats(date, out var result))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(($"[{date}] correctly parsed as {result}"));
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Parsing [{date}] failed");
        }
    }
}
```

and got this result (I'm in the US, so we use the insane month-day-year format by default):

```
[31.1.1919] correctly parsed as 1/31/1919 12:00:00 AM
[22/01/1957] correctly parsed as 1/22/1957 12:00:00 AM
[1/2/2020] correctly parsed as 2/1/2020 12:00:00 AM
[03/04/1812] correctly parsed as 4/3/1812 12:00:00 AM
[1/2/03] correctly parsed as 2/1/2003 12:00:00 AM
[04/05/06] correctly parsed as 5/4/2006 12:00:00 AM
[15.6.2020] correctly parsed as 6/15/2020 12:00:00 AM
Parsing [30/2/2010] failed
```

That seems a little less crazy.